# difference in Contract.Requires and Contract.Ensures

Tags: c#, contracts

I've looked up the difference on the microsoft site but can't really see the difference. links to the website are below

- [Contracts.Ensures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.ensures.aspx)
- [Contract.Requires](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412892%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Any additional explaination would be great

Using visual studio c#

Answer (score 9):

`Requires` is a *precondition*, meaning that the condition specified must be true **prior** to the method being invoked. `Ensures` is a *postcondition*, meaning that the method guarantees that the condition specified will be true **after** the method call is complete.

Preconditions and/or postconditions may be violated *while* the method is executing: the tests are done upon entry to and exit from of the method, respectively. An *invariate condition* is a contract that says that the specified condition always holds true.

Read [Bertrand Meyer](http://se.ethz.ch/~meyer/)'s [Object-Oriented Software Construction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136291554) for more [much more] detail. [This paper](http://se.ethz.ch/~meyer/publications/computer/contract.pdf) by Meyer is shorter [much shorter].

Comment: nice one. I would also suggest `Provable Code` or `Code Contracts` courses at pluralsight.com. They give a very nice drill down into design by contract using Microsoft Code Contracts